# When clicking a button it's opening a modal window in IE, and my Selenium test times out

Tags: c#, selenium

```
string currentWindow = webDriver.CurrentWindowHandle;
search1.click(QuoteLink);
Console.WriteLine("clicked on the Quote Link");
foreach (string handle in WebDriver.WindowHandles)
{
     if(!handle.Equals(currentWindow))
     {
            WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            Console.WriteLine("Switch Window Completed.");
     }
}
```

when I am clicking on that button it is opening a modal window and after that, I am losing control and showing a timeout error after 60 seconds.

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:34281/session/03e28bf0-27c0-4323-96bd-3dfe0785d866/execute timed out after 60 seconds. `enter code here`

Comment: On which line, are you getting the exception?

Comment: in the 2nd line     ( search1.click(QuoteLink);)

Comment: as I am using JavaScript click for the clicking operation because the web driver click is not working in this case

Comment: it looks like, time out issue, you may be waiting long time before click on it. check your previous step.

Comment: No, I don't use any wait statement before the click.

Comment: Are you sure the modal is a separate browser instance and not just an HTML dialog? Your code is treating it like a separate browser instance (handles).

Comment: It is an HTML dialog